# iOS NowPlayingView in Nativescript (7 / Vue)

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

**Situation**

I have a component playing audio in my nativescript app (recently updated to ns 7). Since the app should continue to play audio when it is in the background or the device is locked, I need a way to control the audio. iOS comes with the [NowPlayingView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/nowplayingview).

**Problem**

Since I can not find a link to this feature in the Nativescript Documentation or a ns plugin for that, I am wondering if and how I could use that feature in my app. I did not yet dig into the "native-land" and was primarly using nativescripts own features. So I do not have any first steps that guide me in the right direction to implement such a feature, if possible at all.

**Question**

Maybe you could help me with some rough tipps or even some code snippets, if you have already implemented the NowPlayingView?

Comment: you can call native code from naativescript. If required, create a plugin in which all you do is import the required framework for the now playing view. my advice, drop nativescript, drop any hybrid solution and go native apps. In 6 month your hybrid app won't compile. those thing are so unreliable, forget about it.

Comment: I was using Text to Speech plugin with NS 6 and it was talking in the background.

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/backgroundexecution

Comment: did you try to run your app in the background?